# I only want to validates_presence_of :group if group_id is not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates_presence_of :group
.
.
.
```

I only want to validate the presence of group if group_id is not nil. Is this possible? Or do I need to write a new validates method?

Comment: You can use Proc or lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use inline if for this

```
validates :group, :presence: true, if: "group_id.present?"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Proc to conditionally execute your validation. See the [Rails Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation) for more.

```
validates_presence_of :group, unless: Proc.new { |category| category.group_id.nil? }
```